# How to tell when a Crystal Report has loaded

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, .net

I am building a Winforms C# application that uses Crystal Reports.

I am loading a dummy report so that the Crystal Reports components are loaded when the user opens a Report. I do this because it takes a lot of time to load the report the first time.

I open a minimized, 0% opacity form containing the dummy report from a backgroundworker. I need to know when the report has loaded completely, so that I know when to close the form. I didn't manage to find an answer on-line, so my question is:

**How can you tell programmatically when a Crystal Report has finished loading?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's nothing official about this in crystal report, so I suggest to workaround using callbacks and YourDummyReport.IsLoaded property.
Hope it helps

Comment: In the end, I have decided to use a Timer and check for the IsLoaded property every 1 second. Your solution would have been a hint and is helpful so I'll mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: I was going to update my answer and add a timer but I don't know why I didn't do it !